# Reporting Services Error : This may be due to a connection failure, timeout or low disk condition within the database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a problem with SSRS report while run report multiple times on deployed URL :

1. SSRS report working fine if you are opening report two/three times
2. But when you open reports multiple times on deployed URL then suddenly SSRS report stops working and showing me below error.
3. When I will restart my System (Where I have deployed my report) then it will work properly.

[image]
I am not able to find out why this is happening.

Comment: Have you looked at the query itself for performance tuning?

Comment: Yes i have already tested that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I got the solution for this problem :

Step 1 : Go To start -> SQL Server Configuration Manager

Step 2 : Select SQL Server Services -> Right click on SQL Server Report Services -> Click Restart

[image]
Now Your Report will run.

[image]

**Cheers !!**